# WARNING: /index.xhtml @22,110 target="#{menuTab.action}": Error writing 'action' on type com.menu.MenuTab

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have the following JSF view `index.xhtml`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="top">
        Menu
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
            <p:menubar>
                <p:submenu label="Admin">
                    <p:submenu label="User">
                        <p:menuitem value="Add User" ajax="true">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{menuTab.action}" value="StudentAdd"/> 
                        </p:menuitem>
                        <p:menuitem value="Edit User" ajax="true">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{menuTab.action}" value="StudentEdit"/> 
                        </p:menuitem>
                    </p:submenu>
                </p:submenu>
            </p:menubar>
        </h:form>
        <p:tabView>
            <c:forEach items="#{menuTab.listOfObjs}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
                <p:tab  title="#{menuTab.value}" closable="true"/>
        </c:forEach>
    </p:tabView>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

And the following managed bean `MenuTab.java`

```
package com.menu;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;


@ManagedBean(name="menuTab")
@SessionScoped
public class MenuTab implements Serializable {

/** Creates a new instance of MenuTest */
public MenuTab() {
}
private String action;
private String value;
private List<String> listOfObjs = new ArrayList();

public String getAction() {
    return action;
}

public void setAction(String action) {
    this.action = action;
    addValue(action);
}
//--------------------------------------

public void addValue(String act) {
    if (listOfObjs.isEmpty()) {
        setValue(act);
        getListOfObjs().add(getValue());
        System.out.println("First Data add First Data add First Data add::::::::::::::::" + value);
    }
    Iterator idvalu = listOfObjs.iterator();
    while (idvalu.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaa=====" + idvalu.next());

        value=act;

        if (idvalu.next().equals(value)) {
            System.out.println("Data Alrady Exite Data =====" + value);
        } 
        else {
            setValue(act);
            getListOfObjs().add(getValue());
            System.out.println("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb=====" + value);
        }

    }

}

/**
 * @return the listOfObjs
 */
public List<String> getListOfObjs() {
    return listOfObjs;
}

/**
 * @param listOfObjs the listOfObjs to set
 */
public void setListOfObjs(List<String> listOfObjs) {
    this.listOfObjs = listOfObjs;
}

/**
 * @return the value
 */
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

/**
 * @param value the value to set
 */
public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

}

When i click Add User menu;tomcat show this massage:

```
aaaaaaaaaaa=====StudentAdd
Jun 24, 2012 3:30:04 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: /index.xhtml @22,110 target="#{menuTab.action}": Error writing 'action' on type com.menu.MenuTab
javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml @22,110 target="#{menuTab.action}": Error writing 'action' on type com.menu.MenuTab
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:139)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.SetPropertyActionListenerHandler$SetPropertyListener.processAction(SetPropertyActionListenerHandler.java:206)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml @22,110 target="#{menuTab.action}": Error writing 'action' on type com.menu.MenuTab

This means that the setter method behind the expression `#{menuTab.action}` has thrown an exception. Look further down in the stacktrace for that exception and then fix the code accordingly based on the information provided in the exception.

A quick glance on the `setAction()` code suggests that the most probable cause is a `NoSuchElementException` because you're calling `Iterator#next()` twice inside the loop. Every time the `next()` is called, it moves to the next element. It does not return the "current" element as you seemed to expect.

Remove the following line:

```
System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaa=====" + idvalu.next());
```

or at least assign it to a variable

```
String next = idvalu.next();
System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaa=====" + next);

if (next.equals(value)) {
    // ...
```